# fixed sidebar on scroll with Js

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar

I've spent hours trying to figure out why I cant seem to get a sidebar fixed on scroll with javscript. 
At this point I dont know if it's something in the js or css.  I've tried to add a classList of "fixed" - didnt work.. and when I add sticky it just pushes down the main text .
The idea is for the nav bar and sidebar to be fixed once the user scrolled the entire header but the main text should be scrolled while the two other elements are fixed.

````
code here -> https://codepen.io/mullerz/pen/GRpKQVy```
help please and thanks a million
````

Answer (score 0):

CSS `position: sticky` is the only thing that you would need. You already use it somewhere on the nav, but because of the JavaScript code it messes things up. Comment out your `fixNav` function and scroll event listener.

Instead use CSS to say when the `nav` and `#sidebar` elements should be sticky. The sidebar element should have a slight offset because it should sit just below the nav bar. With the `top` property you can set the trigger position when an element becomes sticky. Same goes for `left`, `right` and `bottom`.

Add the following lines to your existing `nav` and `#sidebar` styles and see what happens.

```
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#sidebar{
  position:sticky;
  top: 8vh; /* <-- height of the nav */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/ZEbzxZB

as css try below . I used important because your #sidebar css below it .order of css isportant.

```
.fixed-sidebar{
        position:fixed !important;
    }
```

as script i calculated navbar offset height andt changed padding top to top. for absolute or fixed style u should use top bottom left right .  try below

```
const nav = document.querySelector("#main");
const navTop = nav.offsetTop;
const navHeight = nav.offsetHeight;
const main = document.querySelector(".site-wrap");
const bars = document.querySelector("#bars");
const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
window.addEventListener("scroll", fixNav )  
function fixNav(){
    sidebar.style.top = (nav.offsetTop+navHeight) + "px";
    if(window.scrollY >= navTop){               
            nav.classList.add("fixed");
            main.style.paddingTop = navHeight + "px";
            sidebar.classList.add("fixed-sidebar");

    }else{
            main.style.paddingTop = 0;
              nav.classList.remove("fixed");
            sidebar.classList.remove("fixed-sidebar");
    }
}

bars.addEventListener("click", function(){  
    sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
})
```

Comment: Hi Çagri, indeed it worked. Now I get that I must store in a variable inside the function the  value of top 0 that I defined in css to fixate the nav. Wht i dont get, and this is a basic question related to css is why this only works with the var top and sidebar.style.top before the if condition.   If it is inside the if that i defined that the nav will have a offsettop of zero hoew can i store it before the if condition?

Comment: Hi @Peter I deleted var top edited code a bit.. U can't uuse topNow because it is constant but your nav offset is changable . so for every scroll u need to recalculate offset . u dont need to take it to if condition because offset always gives it to right position.